# SSIS: Insert multiple Excel files with same format but different file name to multiple database table destinations based on the Excel filename

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have been researching this for a while and not found anything explicit.  I have multiple Excel files containing billing information for different projects.  We can think of these as File A for project A, File B for project B and File C for project C.  They are moved from outlook, by rule, to a common folder.

I would like to use SSIS to utilize the file name in determining the destination location. In our very simplified case above, I would like loop through the folder and have File A to be read to Table A, File B to Table B and File C to Table C. All tables are contained within one SQL Server Database. Once complete I would like the files to be moved into set destinations (Folder A, Folder B, and Folder C)

I assume you will have to add a script component to take the file name variable, parse it to recover the A, B, C and use this to direct some sort of IF statement to locate the relevant destination location.

The only other minor complication is that I would want to check each table to ensure I am not adding any duplicate data - assuming I would use a look up component here before each table destination...

I can find information on for each loop containers and dynamically setting source locations, but not dynamic destinations based on file names.

Does this seem like a reasonable undertaking in SSIS and would anyone able to help me on this or perhaps point me to a source that I have yet uncovered?

Any help would be really appreciated - please also let me know if you would like further details.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you could have a data flow task that could feed into dynamic tables on each iteration unless you have the same table structure for Table A, Table B and Table C...So a few questions to see if I can help. How many different projects do you have (A,B,C..)? Are the file names always constant for each project and for you example above, would "A File B" be considered as from Project A or Project B?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, and godzilla2014 - Thanks for the response.  I have been working with SSIS for about 4 months. Beginner - but I like to think I know what is going on... Currently I load the tables individually with SSMS import data.  There would only be three projects (IDs are actually like 1547-3200...). Each Excel file name is the same, each time, for that project (so the file name would be 1547-3200 in the above example). They are always constant.  The information in for example the 1547-3200 would be read into a table called 1547-3200.  The table format for each project is the same.

Comment: ....for example table format is Resource, Project_phase, Hours, Rate.  So @godzilla2014, your reference that the table structure would need to be the same would definitely be the case.

Comment: @Myles - 4 months is a lot of time to learn SSIS and ETL. You need to learn a lot more. Anyway, this may not be the best way, but you can try this - Load excel data into a staging table. Depending on the file name, generate dynamic sql to load data into the right table, from the staging table. Truncate the staging table. Repeat for the remaining excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As read in the comment, We cannot load into multiple tables with in a for-each loop as long as they share different table structure.

If All excel sheets share same structure, we can avoid the complexities. the following steps may help you.

```
1. DFT 1
a.  Develop an SSIS package with a DFT to load all your excel files into a single stage table.
b.  In the table in addition to the excel columns, add a separate column to store file name.
c.  Use a for-each loop with 'Foreach ADO.NET Schema Rowset Enumerator'.
d.  Again it will be help you if excel files share a common file name pattern.(ProjA_140527.xls, ProjA_140528.xls,ProjB_140527.xls etc), 
    so that you can use Proj*.xls to fetch the excel files.

2. DFT 2
a.  After this DFT, add another DFT. use an OLE DB Source taking data from stage table.
b.  After the source, add a conditional split. Write expressions based on excel file name column.
c.  if you have 5 projects, conditional split will have 5 outputs and 1 non-matching output.
d.  Map each project tables to conditional split outputs.
```

Comment: Many thanks for this!  This seems a pragmatic approach and makes sense.  My hope was that the filename variable itself could be  utilized, programmatically, to map the ODBC destination table name. Another thought is... would you be able to run a SQL Task the uses the filename variable in a SQL statement to insert the data into the relevant table (as the column mapping would be the same).  You might need to do some scripting to reassign the filename variable to equal the table name...bit of a hack perhaps...

Comment: You are right, you can insert the filename through sql statement.